# Presenting modal view controller makes its tableview move down little by little

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Dismissing/presenting a modal view controller which contains a tableview makes the table go down one row each time. Repeating presenting/dismissing pushes the table downwards out of the view in the end.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Giving us an idea of your code might help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed it.

This solves the problem:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
```

The property is inherited from `UIScrollView` and it specifies where the content of the scrollview (as tableview is a scrollview) should stay related to scroll's bounds.